# URDF files can not work on rviz ( ERROR on terminal )

Tags: ros, urdf, xacro, urdf-tutorial, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello  Everyone,  I am following ROS/ Tutorials and I came aorund URDF Tutorials but  relevant  both URDF and XACRO examples  I couldnt run , I couldnt stimulate on rviz.  After all Trying and all searching to answer what is problem, I found myself here so ; Could you lead me ?
when I  command

```
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=urdf/03-origins.urdf  
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=urdf/05-visual.urdf
$ check_urdf my_robot.urdf
$ urdf_to_graphiz my_robot.urdf
$ evince test_robot.pdf
```

there is the error  saying like this:

```
atilay@atilayLnxPC:/opt/ros/indigo$
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch
model:=urdf/03-origins.urdf ...
logging to /home/atilay/.ros/log/4963afa4-ec9f-11e4-8c36-00231518f52c/roslaunch-atilayLnxPC-7548.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile. Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py",
line 298, in main
    p.start()   File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py",
line 260, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()   File
"/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py",
line 209, in _start_infrastructure
    self._load_config()   File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py",
line 124, in _load_config
    roslaunch_strs=self.roslaunch_strs,
verbose=self.verbose)   File
"/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py",
line 451, in load_config_default
    loader.load(f, config, verbose=verbose)   File
"/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py",
line 730, in load
    self._load_launch(launch, ros_config, is_core=core,
filename=filename, argv=argv,
verbose=verbose)   File
"/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py",
line 702, in _load_launch
    self._recurse_load(ros_config, launch.childNodes, self.root_context,
None, is_core, verbose)   File
"/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py",
line 646, in _recurse_load
    self._param_tag(tag, context, ros_config, verbose=verbose)   File
"/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py",
line 95, in call
    return f(*args, **kwds)   File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py",
line 264, in _param_tag
    value = self.param_value(verbose, name, ptype, *vals)   File
"/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/loader.py",
line 463, in param_value
    with open(textfile, 'r') as f:
**IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'urdf/03-origins.urdf'**
```

My  idea is that   this error occurs related with urdf  , urdf_parser_plugin and  liburdfdom-tools ..  I searched that liburdfdom-tools is old and not related with ROS    but I have been installed that and I  couldnt fix it.. there is the time important for develop the robot for my Thesis   lead me please..
what can I do for fix it ?
by the way I use ROS / indigo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207972/urdf-files-can-not-work-on-rviz-(-error-on-terminal-)/) by [Atilay Mayadag](https://answers.ros.org/users/22277/atilay-mayadag/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error tells you that `urdf/03-origins.udf` cannot be found. If the file does exist, it's likely that you forgot to execute those commands in the correct working directory.

See [Error in Building a Visual Robot Model with URDF from Scratch](http://answers.ros.org/question/141466/error-in-building-a-visual-robot-model-with-urdf-from-scratch/) and / or [No Visual Robot Model with URDF](http://answers.ros.org/question/127356/no-visual-robot-model-with-urdf/).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Atilay Mayadag](https://answers.ros.org/users/22277/atilay-mayadag/) on 2015-04-27**:
is it true  tick ?   and thank you for answering  , and sorry for my fault about forum

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-27**:
No problem.